# ¿Cómo obtener todos los archivos de varias carpetas y convertirlos en encabezados de archivo csv?

Tags: c#, pdf, csv

Tengo una carpeta maestra la cual contiene varios sub carpetas y en cada de esas sub carpetas hay archivos PDF.

Lo que busco hacer es tomar cada una de esos archivos pdf y usar ese nombre para que sean agregados como valor de una columna y crear así un archivo csv.

Ejemplo:

Si tengo un archivo llamado miReporte.pdf. Quisiera que ese nombre de ese archivo sea parte de otro archivo csv pero que pertenezca al valor de una columna determinada.

El nombre de la columna no importa, lo importate es obtener todos estos Pdf como valor para poder filtrarlos.

Mi problema es que tengo mas de 10000 archivos pdf con diferents nombres, y quiera crear un archivo csv para asi poder filtrarlos en excel y verlos.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitás es un archivo CSV que contenga los nombres de todos los PDF de determinadas carpetas? ¿para qué tiene que ser necesario c#? Podrías directamente redireccionar la salida de DIR (o ls en linux) a un archivo y abrirlo en Excel.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que busco hacer. Puse C# porque me siento mas familiar con este, pero si tienes alguna otra solucion tambien podria mirarla
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede hacer con un comando en una terminal.

```
for /R %A in (*.*) do @echo %~nA >>lista.csv
```

[image: Ejemplo de carpetas anidadas con PDFs]

El archivo resultante contendrá:

```
pdf1 
pdf2 
pdf3 
pdf4 
pdf5 
pdf6 
pdf7
```

Comment: Me resulta, pero necesitaria que el resultado me mostrara la extension de cada archivo ya que necesito filtrar los nombres segun la extension de cada archivo. La solucion solo me muestra el nombre pero sin extension

Comment: Si investigás un poco vas a ver que le podés agregar cualquier dato al resultado. Si le agregás una x te trae la extensión también (%~nxA). [Using Batch parameters](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: También podés traer sólo los PDFs si cambiás (\*.\*) por (\*.pdf). O sólo los archivos que comiencen con "c" y sean .pdf, por ejemplo: (c*.pdf).

Comment: Si me resulto extupendamente! Muchas gracias!!!!